# Opening a Base64 encoded PDF in native pdf viewer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on generating pdfs that contain the image from a html canvas element. I've managed to get an implementation of that working, but I'm having trouble opening the result in a useful way.

PDF.dataURI() returns a string that looks like `data:application/pdf;base64,BASE64_ENCODED_PDF_HERE`.

I'm currently using `window.location = certificate.dataURI()` to open up the pdf. I already tried `window.open`, but Safari wouldn't play nice with it.

RESULTS:

In Firefox, this saves a file that is a random name, followed by .pdf(1).part.
In Safari (desktop and mobile), it opens the PDF in the same tab, but doesn't bring up any pdf viewer interface.
In Chrome, it opens the PDF in the same tab and brings up the PDF interface.

Basically, my question is how to open a string of that format inside of the browser as a PDF, ideally in a new tab.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you already have a look at [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)?

Comment: Is it a problem if you sent it to the server and have it serve a normal version of the document?

Answer (score 4):

You can use iframes to view the pdf like below

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64, your_base64_data" type="application/pdf">
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?&embedded=true"></iframe>
</object>
```

Comment: does this work only with pdf? I tried it with png and it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Shahar, I have too worked only on pdf as it was for native PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `document.location.href` ?

you can try to control UI interface for PDF viewer from appropriate options inside generated pdf but browser may ignore it, so as al